# Reset Popular post query?

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts

I am using the following code to display most read articles. I think it takes the lifetime of the articles as it displays very old articles first. How can I reset it - weekly?

in my function.php

```
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $countKey = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $countKey, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $countKey);
        add_post_meta($postID, $countKey, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $countKey, $count);
    }
}
```

Display in my page

```
<?php
                            query_posts (array (
                            'posts_per_page' => 5,
                            'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
                            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                            'order' => 'DESC',
                            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
                            ));
                            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                            ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                            <?php
                            endwhile; endif;
                            wp_reset_query();
                            ?>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that storing post views in post meta and making a write query on each page to update the value is extremely unreliable, and prone to race conditions. You will be seeing significant undercounting, and increased server load, especially once more than a few people visit the site. This can be replicated by opening a link multiple times in quickly in a browser. Additionally, querying via post meta is very very expensive/slow. Consider instead pulling the data in from Google Analytics or Jetpack Stats. Also avoid `query_posts`, instead use `get_posts` or `WP_Query`, or `pre_get_posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok *resetting* it weekly - as in have views start from 0 every Monday - rather than trying to show the most read in the last 7 days, then the simplest change would be to have a different meta key for every week of the year. Then when you query the posts, you just query the view count for the current week of the year:

You can do this by just changing this:

```
$countKey = 'post_views_count';
```

To this:

```
$countKey = 'post_views_count_' . date( 'YW' );
```

`date( 'YW' )` will give you a number like `201831`, which represents the 31st week of 2018, so each week will get its own meta key like `post_views_count_201831`.

Then when you query the posts, change:

```
'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
```

To use the meta key for the current week:

```
'meta_key' => 'post_views_count_' . date( 'YW' ),
```

This does mean that when the week switches over you'll briefly have no posts with views, since the count has started over. One thing you could do is change the query so that for 1 day it will continue to show the popular posts from the previous week, while still counting views for the current week:

```
'meta_key' => 'post_views_count_' . date( 'YW', strtotime( '-1 day' ) ),
```

Comment: Must I use WP_Query to get the posts or is the normal query sufficient enough?

Comment: OK Your solution works perfect thanks. Just let me know whether I must query_post or WP_Query?

Comment: The code will work regardless of which you choose, but you should never use `query_posts()`. Use `WP_Query`. See the note in the description [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/).